# Invalid greeting from server

Tags: freebsd

I'm trying to csup and i'm getting "Invalid greeting from server"

```
su-3.2# /usr/bin/csup -z -h cvsup.freebsd.org /usr/share/examples/cvsup/standard-supfile
Connected to 72.233.193.64
Invalid greeting from server
su-3.2#
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the server is down.  It might be updating or have a problem; try again later.

Comment: Please contact the system administrator if the problem persists